# What do LED intensity values corresponds?

Tags: arduino, led

I was trying to connect an LED with an Arduino and control the brightness. From tutorials i have seen than the intensity can be varied from 0(dark) to 255(bright). I would like to know what do these values mean? How this value is related to the illuminance or lux units?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a software question.  You might want to try another Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intensity can be varied from 0 (dark) to 255 (bright) modifiying the duty cycle of the signal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_cycle). You can use `analogWrite()` in Arduino for doing it. Here the site: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM.

Answer (score 0):

That 0 - 255 number represents the "duty cycle of the PWM" (google that) that you are giving to the LED. Whether 0 is fully ON or fully OFF is dependent on how you wire the LED.  With analogWrite you are sending pulses of 5V and 0V to the pin.  With the duty cycle set to 0 you are sending 0V all the time.  At 255 you are putting 5V all the time.  At 128 you have a square wave with half at 0 and half at 5V.  All the values in between create a square wave with a larger or smaller percentage of the time at 5V.

See this link for more information https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM